# How to catch NULL value in length mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have table like this

```
Table : test
column1 | column2
aaaaaa  | 113323
(NULL)  | 2331233
2       | 899999
99999   | 222222
abc     | 13123
jul     | 98282
```

I tried to find where the length of word in column1 less than 4, so i used this queries.

```
select * from test where length(column1) < '4'
```

I only get this :

```
column1 | column2
abc     | 13123
jul     | 98282
2       | 899999
```

why my queries didn't catch the NULL value ? is there something wrong with my queries ? what i expect was like this

```
column1 | column2
(NULL)  | 2331233
abc     | 13123
jul     | 98282
2       | 899999
```

I have another solution like used the `where column1 is null` but its not working to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use `COALESCE` here to replace `NULL` with empty string, and then do the length comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE LENGTH(COALESCE(column1, '')) > 4;
```

Answer (score 7):

`NULL` is not a string, so you cannot compare `length` to it.

try:

```
select * from test where length(column1) < '4' or column1 is NULL;
```

So if that value `(NULL)` is indeed null, it will get matched, but if it's some weird/modified version and not a real MySql `NULL`, it will not get matched